# A problem getting 'author (forthcoming a, b)' in citation; natbib

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, bibdesk

I'm trying to cite two forthcoming publications of a single author, storing them under cite-keys 'Author' and 'Author1', and letting the year for each entry be 'forthcoming.' (I'm using `BibDesk` software to store bibliography and `natbib` package.) However, while in the Bibliography at the end of the document I correctly get 'Author. forthcoming a., Author forthcoming b.' as two separate entries, in the body of the text, using `\citet{Author, Author1}`, I get 'Author (forthcoming a,f)'.

I cannot figure out why I am getting 'f' instead of 'b' here, and am not sure how to detect the problem. 
**EDIT:** Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\citet{Author, Author1}




\bibliography{TestBib}  
   \bibliographystyle{phil_review}
\nocite{*} 

\end{document}
```

The bibliography style is [phil_review.bst](http://tedsider.org/latex/phil_review.bst).

The `Test' bibliography has only two entries.
The first entry:

```
cite-key: "Author"

Author: "Name Author"

Title: "Title"

Book title: "In Title"

Publisher: "Test Press"

Year: "forthcoming." 

Editors: "Editors"
```

The second entry:
    cite-key: "Author1"

```
Author: "Name Author"

Title: "Test"

Journal: "Journal Test"

Year: "forthcoming."
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with the data producing such an output.

Comment: Not a full solution, but a work-around: write `year = "{forthcoming}",`, i.e., add an extra pair of curly braces. You'll get a natbib warning about an "improper alphabetic constant"; just hit return to finish the compilation.